# npm scriptsでif文を使用したい

Tags: node.js

現在、下記のような　packackge.json を使用して、TravisCIで`npm publish`を実行した時に、hookするようなスクリプトを使用しています。

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": "if [ $TRAVIS ]; then npm run compile; fi"
  }
}
```

上記は、bash環境下であれば動くのですが、例えば Windows から`npm install`を実行したタイミングでもhookしてしまうので、`$TRAVIS was unexpected at this time.`となり、インストールを行えません。

Windows環境下で、`npm publish`/`npm install`のタイミングで、環境変数TRAVISを参照し、処理を分岐させることは可能でしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": "node -e \"if(process.env.TRAVIS){}else{process.exit(1)}\" && echo true || echo false"
  }
}
```

上記であれば、Win/Mac両方とも動作しました。

<del>（自己回答になります）Evaluate scriptを使い、**Travisであれば後方ステートメントを実行する**ことで、ifを実現できました。これはwin/mac両方で動作します。</del>

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": "node -e \"if(!process.env.TRAVIS)process.exit(1)\" && npm run compile"
  }
}
```

<del>上記は、bash系の`"`内で`!`が評価されるため動作せず、逆に`"`を`'`に変えると、bat系で動作しません。</del>

```
$ node ifTravis.js && npm run compile
```

<del>という風に、素直に別ファイル内で同様の処理を書いて、実行した方がよさそうです。</del>